# Visual Studio 2012 C# - Importing a DLL

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio-2012, dll, reference

I am actually trying to use a DLL on a C# project. The problem is, whenever I try to import it in my project by adding it as a reference, I get this error message :

> A reference to "C:\FilePath\LnkEMP.dll" could not be added. 
>   Check that the file is an assembly or a valid COM component

The library is "LnkEMP.dll", used for a program called Expert/M Plus. I need this library to interract with this program. 
I think that this DLL is made in C++, which could be one of the reason that my C# project can't load it. 
I tried to make a C++ Library and importing it, but this time I had another error message :

> A reference to "C:\FilePath\LnkEMP.dll" could not be added,
>   because it is not an assembly .NET, or not a registered ActiveX control

Do you have any idea of what should I do to get it work ?

Comment: You are having a poor start with it.  The product is too obscure to expect support for it on a Q+A site, contact the vendor to find help.

Comment: Did you manage to get this working? And would you mind sharing your knowledge with the world (or al least me)? I'm actually having the exact same issues as you are. I'm basically trying to achieve the exact same thing... Expert/M is such a pain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fall back on dynamic loading of dll using Win32 api calls.  There should be lots of examples of dynamical loading/calling of external dll.  Hopefully your dll comes with doc on how to use it.